# Is there any example on the web how Collision Detection can be implemented with Shaders?

Tags: opengl, collision-detection, glsl, webgl, shader

Is there any OpenGL, OpenGL ES or WebGL code example on the web how 3D Collision Detection can be implemented with Shaders (preferably GLSL)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GLGE](http://www.glge.org/) has shader based collision detection.  See [this demo](http://www.glge.org/demos/leveldemo/). (WASD,spacebar and mouse to move around.  Notice how you collide with walls, etc.)

If you look at the source code, collision detection is handled with the code

```
var ray=gameScene.ray(origin,[0,0,1]);
```

If you follow this into `glge.js` you'll see how this is implemented with a special render mode `GLGE.RENDER_PICK` (which in turn uses a picking fragment shader in `pkfragStr`).